git clone with https using token
I am using a MacOS, and i have my ssh keys, when I try to git clone from gitLab using git link it works great, it uses my ssh key. But when I try with an http link, it asks me my login and password. and even if I give the login/pwd it doesn't work, because of 2FA. how can I make git uses my ssh key/ or gitLab token to clone repositories ?
Best,

When you want to clone a repo from GitLab, make sure to click on "Copy URL" button next to ssh address after pressing the Code button. If you've linked an ssh-keypair of your GitLab account with your Computer, typing git clone <copied ssh address> will do the trick.
"Copy URL" button marked orange on image below:


the ssh link works, but i have scriptes how uses only https links. and the 2FA blocks them.

You mean you have some scripts, that use HTTPS links of other (not your) repos to clone and you want to use exactly HTTPS type of connection instead of SSH? I don't see any issue with changing HTTPS links to SSH links provided the script is executed on host with linked set of ssh keypair.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk, it was my addressing to questionee, edited.
